# Rev Slider animation start on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, wordpress, revolution-slider

I'm using the RevSlider plugin on WordPress and would like the animation to start upon scroll instead of when the page loads. I have found this script that supposedly works for others but when I try it I get an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.     353plugins.js?ver=4.1:3198 
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.     plugins.js?ver=4.1:3198 stWidget.widgetLoadbuttons.js?ver=4.1:1 (anonymous function)

below is the script, anyone able to help with this?

```js
(function() {
 
 var win, slider, sliderHeight, sliderPaused, winHeight;
 
 // Change the "revapi1" part here to whatever "revapi" name that your slider uses
 slider = revapi2.revresume();.on('revolution.slide.onloaded', function() {
 
 win = jQuery(window).on('scroll', checkScroll).on('resize', sizer);
 sizer();
 
 });
 
 function sizer() {
 
 sliderHeight = slider.height();
 winHeight = win.height();
 checkScroll();
 
 }
 
 function checkScroll() {
 
 var scrTop = win.scrollTop(),
 offset = slider.offset().top;
 
 if(offset <= scrTop + winHeight && offset + sliderHeight >= scrTop) {
 
 if(sliderPaused) slider.revresume();
 sliderPaused = false;
 
 }
 else {
 
 if(!sliderPaused) slider.revpause();
 sliderPaused = true;
 
 }
 
 }
 
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax mistake on line 6: `...revresume();.on('re...` should be `...revresume().on('re...` without the semicolon

Comment: Great thanks! That helped, it now at least appears on the page after saving the custom script instead of not showing up at all, however unfortunately it still does not function as it should (runs on page load instead of scroll) and the error is the same :/

Comment: if it helps, the site is http://csprintingmt.com, its the "glassware" slider just there on the home page. I've periodically made the site public so you can see.